# Array formula using small function

Tags: excel

For the following table, the formula below is not working using the ctrl + Shift + Enter shortcut.

```
Column 1      Values
A               4
A               9
A               2
B               64
B               11
C               34
```

Formula >  {=SMALL(IF(Column 1=A,C2:C4),1}

Comment: Assuming columns A and C for the data, it should be: `=SMALL(IF(A2:A6="A",C2:C6),1)`. Also "not working" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will take your note onboard.